# inovado wordpress too many elements in menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hay i m using a inovado wordpress theme and i have been struggled from many hoers with my menu and my footer.
Situation is that i have to many elements in my menu and my flags for changing language are going to second row (menu is to long).
http://www.wesby-solutions.com/index.php/accueil/

Second challenge is my responsive footer, i have already changed for desktop and tablet but cannot find for mobile(css file). 
When i m changing resolution for mobile the logo is in bad position.

Sow i have two questions:
- in witch files i have to change menu with or some othere solution for keeping menu in one line.
- witch css file is commanding a mobile styles and where can i find this file?
please help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 862 of /wp-themes/inovodo/style.css change padding from this

```
#navigation ul li a {
  height: 87px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 0px 15px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  line-height: 90px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #666666;
}
```

to

```
#navigation ul li a {
  height: 87px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 0px 15px;
  padding: 0px 3px;
  line-height: 90px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #666666;
}
```

and for footer you can add media queries to this element in the same style.css file.

```
.copyright-text img#footer-img-logo
```